# T-SQL group by date instead of datetime

Tags: sql-server, datetime

```
select [DateTime (UTC)],  
sum([messages sent external]) as 'messages sent external',
sum([messages sent internal]) as 'messages sent internal',
sum([messages received external]) as 'messages received external',
sum([messages received internal]) as 'messages received internal',
max([Message Latency Internal High]) as 'Message Latency Internal High', 
max([Message Latency Internal Avg]) as 'Message Latency Internal Avg' from dbo.Monthly_MailFlowStats_2014_03 group by [DateTime (UTC)] order by [DateTime (UTC)] asc
```

The results show all the data in datetime by each hour of the day. Can I trim the datetime to only be date so the results show data for the day and not hour of the day?

```
This: 
2014-03-01 

instead of:
2014-03-01 00:00:00.000
2014-03-01 01:00:00.000
2014-03-01 02:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select cast([DateTime (UTC)] AS date) AS [Date],  
sum([messages sent external]) as 'messages sent external',
sum([messages sent internal]) as 'messages sent internal',
sum([messages received external]) as 'messages received external',
sum([messages received internal]) as 'messages received internal',
max([Message Latency Internal High]) as 'Message Latency Internal High', 
max([Message Latency Internal Avg]) as 'Message Latency Internal Avg' 
from dbo.Monthly_MailFlowStats_2014_03 
group by cast([DateTime (UTC)] AS date) 
order by [Date] asc
```

Comment: I really appreciate everyone's help. Metaphor has the answer I'm looking for. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just trim the time portion off:

```
select DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, [DateTime (UTC)]), 0) [DateTime (UTC)],  
    sum([messages sent external]) as 'messages sent external',
    sum([messages sent internal]) as 'messages sent internal',
    sum([messages received external]) as 'messages received external',
    sum([messages received internal]) as 'messages received internal',
    max([Message Latency Internal High]) as 'Message Latency Internal High', 
    max([Message Latency Internal Avg]) as 'Message Latency Internal Avg' 
from dbo.Monthly_MailFlowStats_2014_03 
group by DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, [DateTime (UTC)]), 0) 
order by [DateTime (UTC)] asc
```

Note that there are several ways to trim off the time portion of a date; this is just one of them

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on SQL Server 2008+:

```
select
    CAST([DateTime (UTC)] AS DATE) AS 'Date (UTC)',
    sum([messages sent external]) as 'messages sent external',
    sum([messages sent internal]) as 'messages sent internal',
    sum([messages received external]) as 'messages received external',
    sum([messages received internal]) as 'messages received internal',
    max([Message Latency Internal High]) as 'Message Latency Internal High',
    max([Message Latency Internal Avg]) as 'Message Latency Internal Avg' 
from
    dbo.Monthly_MailFlowStats_2014_03 
group by
    CAST([DateTime (UTC)] AS DATE)
order by
    [DateTime (UTC)] asc
```